# How do I wiki-edit the blog?

Tags: support, blog, editing

I was reading a blog post and noticed some typos. How can I help by fixing them? I cannot seem to find the `edit` button I know from SE Questions & Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog is currently run through Wordpress, and does not operate on the same principles as the QA sites.

If you make me or one of the site moderators aware of the typos, we will correct them.

Comment: -1 because this is a stupid way to have a community driven blog. accept because it happens to be the status quo.